# What are hardlinks on UNIX? How do they vary from copies?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to get a basic understanding of the concept of "Hard and Soft Links" in Linux.
I came across several links online, and they all said that one must get an understanding of the Unix file-system before understanding what hard and soft links are.
I will first write what I got so far, mainly for you to correct me if I'm wrong...(I'm aware that I might over simplify things, this is for the sake of... well... simplifying things):

- Every file (or folder) on a Unix file-system is identified not by its name, but by a **number** that represents a data-structure called an *inode*.
- The inode contains information about the file it refers to, like permissions, size, location on the disk and more...
- A directory (folder) in a Unix file-system, is actually no more than a **list**; a *name-to-inode#* mapping, of the files it contains. this means, that a file-name is separated from the file-content (the actual data on the disk).

So we could have something like this:
[image]

I also read, and this is where I get confused, that the name-inode map for a file isn't necessarily unique, meaning that a directory can contain two different file names that maps to the same inode number (and thus to the same file in the file system, and thus to the same actual content data on the disk), **and** two different directories may contain identical name-inode mappings (how is it different from "coping a folder with all its content"?) so using either pathname will lead to the same actual content on disk... How exactly can you name a file with two different names on linux, and what is it good for anyway?

btw, is there some linux tool that shows the information for a given inode?

Comment: `stat foo` shows the inode number &c. for the file at `foo`.

Comment: ...that said, this isn't a question about programming; SuperUser is probably a better place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
how is it different from copying a folder with all its content?
```

Lets say you have an 8GB USB stick with an arbitrary folder which is 6GB in size. You want the folder to be accessible from 2 different locations e.g. /so_very_tired/shared_big_folder and /james/foobar but copying in both location wont fit of the USB stick. So you make a reference or symbolic link to the file/folder. The actual location for this folder can be anywhere, for example in /6GB_FOLDER

In order to do this so we create a symbolic link from /so_very_tired/shared_big_folder => /6GB_FOLDER and /james/foobar => /6GB_FOLDER

Now accessing the directory /so_very_tired/shared_big_folder and /james/foobar will lead to /6GB_FOLDER.

To find more information of files and indoes, open up a command prompt and type

```
$man ls
```

You can use `ls -i` to list the inode numbers for files

They are mostly used when you want to place a link to a file where the file doesn't exist e.g You have a configuration file for a server placed in /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/ and in order to enable it you want to place it in the /etc/site-enabled folder but you don't want to make a copy. By creating a symbolic link all edits to the file in the sites-available folder are also made to the file pointed to by the symbolic link in sites-enabled. This is because one is the file and the other points the the same file.

To create a symbolic link use

```
ln -s /existing-file /symbolic-link
```

Comment: `The actual location for this folder can be anywhere`--Can it be in other than the two folders mentioned and these two will point a symbolic link at that location to access? Please answer this and +1 is waiting for you!

Comment: Yes, there where 3 folders mentioned. It can be anywhere on the filesystem; even across different supported filesystems.**

Comment: THANKS @James.An upvote for you.

Comment: Note that `the actual location for this folder can be anywhere` applies to *symbolic* links — hard links can not cross filesystem boundaries, because each filesystem has its own set of inodes and they can conflict. Some filesystems don't even have inodes; for example your USB stick could be an NTFS or a FAT32 filesystem, but you can create a symlink from your unix disk to point to it, and leave a dangling link when the stick is removed. Hard links can't ever leave dangling links, their link count is decremented when one of the linked files is removed.

Comment: The "actual location" is not under a folder/directory. The actual location is in the file system, in a location (or locations) specified in the inode. A directory entry *refers* to the actual location via the file's inode. We think of a file as being "under" or "within" a directory because all the user-level interfaces make them appear that way.

Comment: @Keith - thanks, for some reason that's not how I was reading it. I think it was the shekhar question and James response (3 folders) that threw me out of the inode/disk-block level into the directory hierarchy level of thought.